# Aurelia: using an SVG from a jspm package

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm using a CSS library ([Salesforce lightning](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com)) that uses SVG for icons. Their markup for an icon is:

```html
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--large slds-icon-standard-opportunity">
  <use xlink:href="path/to/symbols.svg#opportunity"></use>
</svg>
```

I have installed the npm package for this library with jspm. This `path/to/svg/symbols.svg` used for the icons is now in my jspm_packages directory. What is they best way for me to refer to this path in my own component? I am considering a couple of options:

#### 1. Copy the resource to my own assets folder

Copy the svg file to my own assets folder, and just hard code the link to this file in my component.

#### 2. Link directly to the path in jspm_packages

Don't really want to do this. I also imagine this would be a pain when bundling.

#### 3. Dynamically get the path from jspm_packages

In the same way that you can `<require from="package-name/style.css">` can you get the path of `package-name` as described by jspm in some way?

#### 4. Add resource plugin for SVG files.

A custom handler for requiring markdown files is shown in [this video](https://vimeo.com/153090562) at the 44 minute mark. I tried to do the same for SVG files (and also markdown files as a test) but even copying his example word for word and configuring aurelia to use the plugin did nothing. When trying to do `<require from="package-name/symbols.svg">` aurelia still looks for `symbols.svg.js` suggesting the plugin isn't really being used. Is there a full code example of how this should all work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option #3 (dynamically get the path) should work:

```js
let url = System.normalizeSync('salesforce-ux/design-system/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg') + '#warning';
```

Might be good to create a custom element to encapsulate all the logic. Then you would be able to replace this:

```html
<svg aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon--large slds-icon-standard-opportunity">
  <use xlink:href="path/to/symbols.svg#opportunity"></use>
</svg>
```

With this:

```html
<suds-icon icon="opportunity" size="large"></suds-icon>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked with one other addition. I had to set `"defaultExtension": false` just for this package in `config.js` as otherwise `normalizeSync()` was adding `.js` to the url.

Comment: you could try adding a `!` to the end of the url you're normalizing instead of setting `defaultExtension` to false. Not 100% sure that will work though...

Comment: That doesn't have the same effect, unfortunately.